# What is the difference between `str` and `object` data types in `pandas.read_csv`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

According to the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), `pandas.read_csv` allows me to specify a `dtype` for the columns in the CSV file.

> **dtype** : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None
>   Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32} (Unsupported with engine=’python’). Use *str* or *object* to preserve and not interpret dtype.

To treat every column as text data, I can use either

```
df = pandas.read_csv(... , dtype=str)
```

or

```
df = pandas.read_csv(..., dtype=object)
```

As far as I know, these two methods always behave exactly the same. Are there any situations in which these two methods behave differently? If so, what are the differences?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These *had* a subtle difference, until release 0.11.1 (*[see issue #3795](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3795)*).

Every element in a numpy array must have the same size in bytes. The issue with strings is that their size in bytes is not fixed, hence the `object` dtype allows pointers to strings which *do* have a fixed byte size. So in short, `str` has a special fixed width for each item, whereas `object` allows variable string length, or really any object.

In any case, since release 0.11.1 there is an auto-conversion from `dtype=str` to `dtype=object` whenever it is seen, so it does not matter what you use, although I would advise avoiding `str` altogether and just use `dtype=object`.